# jQuery - Check if 2 elements in array have same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class

I'm making a cards game, so i need to check if 2 elements (array in table) are the same, i noticed that the only way to do that is with JQuery, but i'm new with these things, i barely control Javascript, jQuery is a hell for me.

My code looks like this

```
var twoace = "<img src='twoace.png' class='two'>";
var twogold = "<img src='twogold.png' class='two'>";
var onegold = "<img src='onegold.png' class='one'>";
var oneace = "<img src='oneace.png' class='one'>"

// i have a lot more code (sorry for my english) but this is the essential

//initial array
tablecards = [deckcard[0], deckcard[1], deckcard[2], deckcard[3]];
document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = tablecards[0];
document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML = tablecards[1];
document.getElementById("table3").innerHTML = tablecards[2];
document.getElementById("table4").innerHTML = tablecards[3];

// here i add a card to the table
tablecards.push(handcard[0]);

//now i have this 
tablecards = [deckcard[0], deckcard[1], deckcard[2], deckcard[3], handcard[4]];
document.getElementById("table5").innerHTML = tablecards[4];
```

How do i check if "tablecards[4]" and "tablecards[1]" (or any other) has same class?

Comment: `tablecards[4].className == tablecards[1].className` ?

Comment: What is `deckcard[0]`...?

Comment: @BeNdErR - in the game will be 10 cards in the table, that would be  10 lines per card? 100 lines only to check if the class are the same? that's crazy, also would make the code "dirty".                                        @T J - Those are cards taken from the deck then i put them in the table

Comment: I'd strongly suggest adding another class to each of the 'cards' (`.card`, for example), then creating the array with `$('.card').get()` (or `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.card'), 0)`). But, that aside, on what event do you want to compare these elements' classes? On `click`, `DOMReady`/`load`..?

Comment: @DavidThomas OnClick with a button made for that

Comment: Well, you haven't shown us the button, or described your event-handler (how, for example, does your script know which card elements to compare? What should happen when, or if a match is found? Or when no match is found?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length` attribute tells you how many elements are using that specific class:

```
var numOnes = $('.one').length;
```

So if `numOnes` is greater than 1 then you can assume that more than two elements are using that specific class.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, with some changes i did exactly what i wanted to, Many Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
~(' '+tablecards[4].className+' ').indexOf(' '+<your class here>+' ');
```

This will tell if you have a class in that element or not.

This is one of the fastest ways to do this: no jQuery, no Regex, just a simple linear search.